# How can I get a Gdk.Window task icon or title?

Tags: window, gtk, vala, gdk, genie

I'm trying with:

```
//valac *.gs --pkg gtk+-3.0 

init
    Gtk.init(ref args)
    var ventana= new win()
    ventana.inicio()

    Gtk.main()


class win:Gtk.Window


    def inicio()

        var button= new Gtk.Button()
        button.clicked.connect(resizer)
        this.add(button)
        this.show_all()
    def resizer()
        var a=Gdk.Screen.get_default().get_window_stack()
        a.foreach(allwin)

    def allwin (w:Gdk.Window)
        var a=w.get_type_hint()
        if a!= Gdk.WindowTypeHint.DESKTOP

            w.resize(200,200)
            var iconpix= w.get_icon() //don't exist // [changed]
            var title= w.get_title() //don't exist // [changed]
            print "window"
```

But those methods don't exist. Why? I don't know.
Any suggestions? I have tryed with Wnck but i get errors too.

Comment: You're using those methods as members of a `TypeHint`, which doesn't have functions. The `Gdk.Window` probably isn't what you want either, since that only serves for drawing on a `Gtk.Window`, which handles the icon and title itself. You really want to be asking your main `Gtk.Window` for its icon and title.

Comment: This question could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/212851). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, yes is my error. But, anyway i don't find ways to get icons or title.

Comment: Sorry Jens, I understand you. My goal is a desktop panel with a task bar of running apps. I want to get of all windows of the desktop them icon and title. The way to get them will be gdk, wnck ...

Comment: If you only want to support X11 you could call X11.get_window_property with the appropriate window property names.(_NET_WM_NAME and _NET_WM_ICON_NAME). See also https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.4/ar01s05.html

Comment: The atoms are called `X11.XA_WM_NAME` and `X11.XA_WM_ICON_NAME`

Comment: Thanks Jens. It could be one way.

Answer (score 2):

You correct that `WNCK` is the way to go.  `Gdk` can only see the windows created by your program. `Wnck` gives you access to all the windows being managed by the Window Manager. Your approach should work as I have done the same with a `dock` I wrote for `Puppy Linux` in `Genie`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that with Gdk is imposible. I have tryed (on more time) with Wnck library giving to a C compiler this '-DWNCK_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE' and works but with a warning: *Unhandled action type _OB_WM_ACTION_UNDECORATE*

```
//valac *.gs --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg libwnck-3.0 -X '-DWNCK_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE'

init
    Gtk.init(ref args)
    var ventana= new win()
    ventana.inicio()
    ventana.resizer()
    Gtk.main()


class win:Gtk.Window

    won:weak GLib.List of Wnck.Window

    def inicio()

        var button= new Gtk.Button()
        button.clicked.connect(resizer)
        this.add(button)
        this.show_all()

    def resizer()
        won= Wnck.Screen.get_default().get_windows()
        won.foreach(allwin)

    def allwin(w:Wnck.Window)
        if w.is_skip_tasklist() or w.is_skip_pager()
            pass
        else
            print w.get_name()
```